# No Such Method Error: Class List<Category> has no instance getter 'entries' Receiver : Instance (length:5 ) of growable list

Tags: flutter

thats my all code i think i got error when i writing  get SelecctedCategories  fonction but i didnt solve it

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Flexible(
  child: Obx(
    () => ListView.builder(
      itemCount: controller.selectedCategories.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return CategoryWidget(
          category: controller.selectedCategories[index],
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);


 var _categories = {
Category("Aksiyon", Color(0xFF21d0d0)): false,
Category("Bilimkurgu", Color(0xFF21d0d0)): false,
Category("Suç", Color(0xFF21d0d0)): false,
Category("Macera", Color(0xFF21d0d0)): false,
Category("Drama", Color(0xFF21d0d0)): false,


}.obs;


void toggle(Category item){_categories [item]= !(_categories[item]?? true};
 print(_categories[item]);
 }

get selectedCategories => categories.entries
.where((element) => element.value).map((e) => e.key)
.toList();
get categories => _categories.entries.map((e) => e.key).toList();}


class Category{
final String name;
final Color color;
 Category(this.name,this.color);}
```

i cant find the problem can someone help me i shared my code.i am waiting your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the line

```
void toggle(Category item){_categories [item]= !(_categories[item]?? true};
   print(_categories[item]);
}
!(_categories[item]?? true};
//Change to
!(_categories[item]?? true);
//The curly brackets after the semicolon
```

---

**UPDATE:**
That's because your `selectedCategories` getter reads from the other getter `categories`
and the `getter` categories return a `list<Category>` not a `Map<Category, bool>`

```
get selectedCategories => categories.entries
    .where((element) => element.value).map((e) => e.key)
    .toList();
get categories => _categories.entries.map((e) => e.key).toList();}
```

to solve this, simply change your `selectedCategories` to read from the map

```
get selectedCategories => _categories.entries
//instead of 
get selectedCategories => categories.entries
```

Comment: i fixed it but problem didnt solve